# How to edit the vector class in godot editor?

Tags: godot

I am using godot editor to create simple game from a website. The issue is in that website they told to use a function called "move_toward", but that function is not available in the vector class of the editor I am using. I found a solution in github that mentions that I should add that "move_toward" function to the vector3.cpp file, but I am unable to find that file anywhere in the project. How to find and edit that vector3 file from the godot editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't edit vector3.cpp from the editor... Because you don't have it!

If you really want to edit vector3.cpp, you can download the Godot source from the github repository, and make a custom build. See [Compiling](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/compiling/index.html).

You would want one of the 3.x branches, of course. Except, well, if you download and compile the 3.3 branch, it already has `move_toward`. You might as well download an official build.

However, to answer how to find and edit vector3.cpp: It is located in the "godot/core/math/" folder, along side vector3.h. You can add a function to vector3.cpp, and don't forget to declare it in the header file.

---

The function `move_toward` was added in Godot 3.2 (the current version at the time of writing is Godot 3.3.2). If you need this function, the simpler solution is to download an updated version of Godot.

*I don't know if the Godot Web editor is relevant to any of this. However, it is also on the version 3.3.2, and `move_toward` is available there (I just checked), so that should be no problem.*

---

With that said, if - for whatever reason - you must use an old version of Godot, we could also emulate `move_toward`.

This code:

```
var result:Vector3 = v.move_toward(to, delta)
```

It is equivalent to this:

```
var result:Vector3 = to
if v != to and v.distance_to(to) < delta:
    result = v + delta * v.direction_to(to)
```

That is, the vector `v` is offset a distance `delta` in the direction from `v` to `to`.

We check `v.distance_to(to) < delta` to sure we don't overshoot going beyond the second vector. And we check `v != to` because when the vectors are equal there is no need for the computation. *Actually, there is a little bit more than that, we will get to it.*

The above code is equivalent to:

```
var result:Vector3 = to
var vd = to - v
if v != to and vd.length() < delta:
    result = v + delta * vd.normalized()
```

There I computed the difference between `v` and `to` and use it to get the distance (`vd.length()`) and direction (`vd.normalized()`).

Which is equivalent to:

```
var result:Vector3 = to
var vd = to - v
var len = vd.length()
if v != to and len < delta:
    result = v + delta * (vd/len)
```

Because the normalized vector is just the vector divided by its length.

And as you can see, that would be a division by zero if the two vectors where equal (the distance from one to the other being zero).

We can check for that zero instead:

```
var result:Vector3 = to
var vd = to - v
var len = vd.length()
if len > 0 and len < delta:
    result = v + delta * (vd/len)
```

If we use the ternary operator conditional, it looks like this:

```
var vd = to - v
var len = vd.length()
var result = v + delta * (vd/len) if len > 0 and len < delta else to
```

And you can compare that to [the source code for `move_toward`](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/core/math/vector3.cpp#L130):

```
Vector3 Vector3::move_toward(const Vector3 &p_to, const real_t p_delta) const {
    Vector3 v = *this;
    Vector3 vd = p_to - v;
    real_t len = vd.length();
    return len <= p_delta || len < CMP_EPSILON ? p_to : v + vd / len * p_delta;
}
```

*The conditional is flipped. And they check if `len` against epsilon (some very small number) instead of checking against zero. Yet, hopefully you can see it acomplishes the same thing.*

We can, of course, wrap our version in a function too. Perhaps put it a helper class:

```
class_name Vector3Helper extends Object

static func move_toward(v:Vector3, to:Vector3, delta:float) -> Vector3:
    var vd = to - v
    var len = vd.length()
    if len > 0 and len < delta:
        return v + delta * (vd/len)

    return to
```

And then instead of writing this code:

```
var result:Vector3 = v.move_toward(to, delta)
```

You can write this code:

```
var result:Vector3 = Vector3Helper.move_toward(v, to, delta)
```

Comment: Thank you @Theraot it was due to the version problem only, after updating the godot, it was working, this helper class solution will be also highly helpful in future

Answer (score 1):

Web-version of Godot Engine has a lot of limitations and it would be better if you could download Godot on your device [Limitations](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/editor/using_the_web_editor.html#doc-using-the-web-editor-limitations).
I've search if you can edit Godot's web files but I couldn't find anything about that. In the executable version of Godot, there is already a built-in function "*move_toward*" and a lot more that you don't have access to in the web editor.